# How to split words in a paragraph when there is a <a> tag with href attribute within the <p> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, split, text-processing

I am working on a web scraping project and I want to split the words in a paragraph when there is an `<a>` tag with `href` attribute within the `<p>` tag. I'm new to scraping and programming in general.

This is the webpage I'm trying to scrape:
https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Of_Banquets,_Bastards_and_Burials

I'm working with `beautiful soup`. My current code returns words that are joined together if there is an `<a>` tag with `href` attribute within the `<p>` tag.

For example, here is the html:

```
<p>
 <br/>
 <a href="/wiki/Dandelion/Netflix_series" title="Dandelion/Netflix series">
  Jaskier
 </a>
 is in a tavern, writing down the excited account of a merchant who hired
 <a href="/wiki/Geralt_of_Rivia/Netflix_series" title="Geralt of Rivia/Netflix series">
  Geralt
 </a>
 to slay a
 <a href="/wiki/Selkiemore" title="Selkiemore">
  selkiemore
 </a>
 plaguing his shipments, only to watch in horror as the monster swallowed the Witcher whole. The merchant insists that Geralt could not have survived, but Jaskier knows better, and is proven right when Geralt himself walks into the tavern, covered head to toe in selkiemore guts, explaining that he had to slay it from the inside. The merchant hurriedly pays Geralt the agreed-upon fee, and the bar patrons clear a path for the reeking Witcher as he orders a tankard of beer to wash out his mouth.
</p>
```

and here is my code:

```
# Read the HTML content from the saved file

with open("yahoo_data.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
html_content = file.read()

# Parse the HTML using BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

# Geralt's timeline

# extract the first paragraph

div_tag = soup.find('div', {'style': 'float:right; width:33%; margin: 0 10px;'})
p_tag = div_tag.find_next('p')
text = p_tag.get_text(strip=True)
print(text+"\n")
```

and the output is:

```
Jaskieris in a tavern, writing down the excited account of a merchant who hiredGeraltto slay aselkiemoreplaguing his shipments, only to watch in horror as the monster swallowed the Witcher whole. The merchant insists that Geralt could not have survived, but Jaskier knows better, and is proven right when Geralt himself walks into the tavern, covered head to toe in selkiemore guts, explaining that he had to slay it from the inside. The merchant hurriedly pays Geralt the agreed-upon fee, and the bar patrons clear a path for the reeking Witcher as he orders a tankard of beer to wash out his mouth.
```

You can see that the combined word:
`aselkiemoreplaguing`

is composed of 3 different words :
`a selkiemore plaguing`

I would need a more systematic and more "pythonic" approach. Thank you

I have tried using the `get_text` method from BeautifulSoup to extract the text from the first paragraph of the web page, but the result is a combined word when there is an `<a>` tag with `href` attribute within the `<p>` tag. I was expecting the words to be separated and not combined.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the separator (which is an empty string by default) to a space:

```py
text = p_tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')
# or, with only positional arguments
text = p_tag.get_text(' ', True)
```